# POST request iOS: what's happening under the hood?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurl

I'm facing a really strange issue and I hope somebody can help me understand where is the problem on which I'm stuck since three days ago.

In simple I make a NSMutableRequest to a simple endpoint where I send (using POST) a json and I'm supposed to receive a response 0 or 1.

The code works the first time the app is run on the device, but somehow it does not work anymore the following times.

To explain myself better, if I uninstall and reinstall the app every time, I get the correct response, but if I run the code twice the second time I get something like [CSRF verification failed] from the endpoint. This error means that I'm not sending the correct format ( or I'm sending something strange).

My question is: how is that possible? Is it possible that I'm sending something else?

The endpoint works correctly because with the android version I don't have any problems...

The code is the following, hope somebody can explain me what is happening under the hood and how I can manage to solve this problem.

```
    NSString *mail       = [profile valueForKey:@"email"];
NSString *provider   = [profile valueForKey:@"provider"];

// making a GET request to endpoint
NSString *baseUrl = ENDPOINT_URL;

NSString *targetUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", baseUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"mail\":\"%@\", \"provider\":\"%@\"}",mail,provider];
NSData *postData=[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetUrl]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];


[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if (data){
          NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSLog(@"Data received: %@", myString);
          if ([myString isEqualToString:@"[\"CSRF validation failed\"]"]){
              NSLog(@"ENDPOINT ERROR");
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] loginAborted];});

          } else {
              NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
              NSLog(@"Data received: %@", json);
              NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[json objectForKey:@"profile_exists"] intValue]];
              if ([value intValue] == 1){
                  //Profile exists.
                  NSLog(@"Profile exists.");
                  [self silentLogin:profile];
              } else if ([value intValue] == 0) {
                  //Profile does not exists.
                  NSLog(@"Profile does not exist.");
                  [self silentRegistration:profile];

              }
              else {
                  //Error.
                  NSLog(@"Error in ENDPOINT VALUE");
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] loginAborted];});
              }
              NSLog(@"%@",json);
          }
      } else {
          NSLog(@"No Data received");
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] loginAborted];});
      }
  }] resume];
```

Comment: This is going to be more related to your endpoint rather than your iOS implementation. You probably just need to set the referer header or CSRF token

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what your suggesting, because if I manually put the the body and the headers into POSTER and make a POST with the data that allegedly I'm sending everything works. Also, like I said if I uninstall the app and I reinstall it everything works. It's like after the first POST, something get saved and I'm sending it with all the requests after...

Comment: The response is being sent by your end point, so I would look there for the answers. By debugging the endpoint you can see why the iOS request is different than Android and other implementations and solve the issue. This code here doesn't seem to have any obvious issues.

Comment: Is there something I can do to like reset all the "settings" of the NSConnection or temporary data or something similar? Because if it works the first time I think something gets saved... If I can reset it my problem will be solved

Comment: You'd be better off solving the root problem, you'll learn something about what you're actually doing rather than forcing a hard reset of the connection. Also I'm not aware of a good way to do that. If I had a good solution for you, I'd post an answer.

Comment: This code itself doesn't appear to be the problem.  The problem is in the code that adds the CSRF token to the request.  If you aren't doing that on either platform, then is probably happening transparently on Android, via cookies.  Make sure those cookies are being stored and re-sent in subsequent requests on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem deleting the cookies every time I make a request. It seems that these cookies are re sent every time.

```
+ (void)clearCookiesForURL: (NSString *)url {
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies = [cookieStorage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
    NSLog(@"Deleting cookie for domain: %@", [cookie domain]);
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

}